# Recommended Editor for Git - Nano or Visual Studio code

Tags: django, git, nano

I am reading through the Djangogirls.org website and they recommend Nano as the default editor when installing Git. I have also installed Visual Studio Code. I'm want to be efficient if I'm doing django and python in Visual Studio should I just use Visual Studio Code as the default editor?

This is the first time I that I'll be using Git or anything similar. It might be that I don't understand it.

Comment: Which OS? On Windows Git comes with Git Bash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter...
You will use the default git editor just to write your commit messages and maybe to setup an interactive rebase. For your normal work (coding, debugging etc.), you can use an IDE or every other editor you want to use.